# Why teach back substitution with row reduction?

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, linear-algebra

Many linear algebra books include two versions of row reduction for solving systems of linear equations:

(1) Reduce to echelon form, and then use back substitution.

(2) Reduce to reduced echelon form (i.e. Gauss-Jordan elimination) and then read off the answer directly from the matrix.

My question is: what are the pedagogical reasons for including both of these approaches?   In particular, why not just use the Gauss-Jordan approach from the beginning?  Is there some advantage to covering back substitution?

Comment: AFAIR, reducing to echelon form is more efficient, but a bit harder to understand...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One reason to know back substitution is that it is relevant when doing numerical mathematics.

A standard procedure to numerically solve linear systems $Ax =b$ especially if one wants to solve for more then one $b$ (which is very common) is to perform an [$LU$-decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of $A$ (or something similar like a [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)), that is one decomposes $A$ as a product of a lower triangular matrix $L$ and an upper triangualar matrix $U$ (sometimes one needs permutation matrices in addition but let us ignore this detail).

Then, one solves the two triangular systems $Ly=b$ and $Ux=y$, *via back substitution,* which is very 'cheap' relative to solving a general linear system ($O(n^2)$ vs $O(n^3)$).

One might now ask why not solve the triangular systems via Gauss--Jordan elimination, and I do not fully oversee momentarily if there is even a difference depending on how one sets things up precisely. Still the two things, reducing to triangular systems and solving the triangular systems, are *conceptually* quite different, and that this difference is stressed when one uses back substitution could be considered as an advantage.

Answer (score 11):

When I teach the $L U$-decomposition, mentioned in quid's answer, I use the following mnemonic:

> Single $\vec{b}$?  Use GE.
>   Several to do?  Use LU.

The point being that if you need to solve $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ for several $\vec{b}$ then the $L U$-method is more efficient than setting up a full Gaussian Elimination for each individual $\vec{b}$.  In terms of the algorithm, the *forward* bit is the same for any $\vec{b}$ but the *back* part depends on $\vec{b}$.  Yes, you can do the back part with a generic $\vec{b}$ and then substitute in for your actual $\vec{b}$, but that doesn't actually save you many computation steps and may cost you some depending on the actual values you're computing with.

Comment: I accept this as a reason why someone might still teach the back-substitution, but the necessity of doing LU is a bit lost on me. Firstly, if the matrix isn't square then you can't do LU. But even if it is, if you had several $b$'s, couldn't you put them all as columns in one big augmented matrix $[A|b_1|b_2|...]$ and do Gauss-Jordan on it and read off all the answers? Alternatively, you could do all the matching row ops on an identity matrix as you go to produce a matrix $E$ (like you do when you find the inverse) and then use it to find the answers $Eb_1$, $Eb_2$ etc.

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA You are incorrect.  You can do LU on any matrix.  The L part will be square and the U part will be the same shape as the original matrix.  LU is also more flexible than doing Gauss-Jordan on a massive matrix since you might not know all of the b's at the same time to make that massive matrix: maybe each b corresponds to the data from a different day and you want to do the calculation as each b is known.  Lastly, back substitution is more efficient than matrix multiplication and the key benefit of LU that I am advocating here is efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @loop-space. When I read online about LU decomposition it said U had to be upper triangular, and I always thought the definition of "upper triangular" included the stipulation that the matrix had to be square. As to the efficiency I can see how back-substitution might use less multiplications and additions overall than matrix multiplication. I am less sure this payoff will offset having to solve $Ux=b$ first every time, but I can possibly believe it.

Comment: ... my problem is that if I as a mathematician (albeit a pure mathematician whith no experience in numerical methods) had to be convinced, will discussing this actually help, say, a first year student? Especially considering the systems they encounter are so small that the difference would be minimal?

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA Actually, I found that students were interested in, and saw the necessity of, efficiency of algorithms more than pure mathematicians tend to be.  Solving Ux=b **is** back-substitution.  What you have to do first is replace b by L^{-1}b (and, incidentally, the LU method computes L^{-1} rather than L so there's no matrix inversion going on here) but as L is triangular, this is a cheap matrix multiplication.

Comment: Sorry. I meant doing $Ux = y$ each time. Anyway, so let me get this straight: the LU method is more-or less the same as doing $[A|I]$ and reducing it to $[U|L^{-1}]$. You calculate $L^{-1}b$ for each $b$ as they appear (daily perhaps) and then back-substitute to solve $Ux = L^{-1}b$? I don't see how that's any better than going from $[A|I]$ to $[rref(A)|E]$ and calculating $Eb$. But as I said I've never studied numerical methods. Probably best for me personally not to tell students right now or I'd just confuse them... Thanks for the discussion though.

Answer (score -1):

If both approaches are known, then one can be used as a check on the other. If the answers disagree, there has been a mistake somewhere.